# Azure Webapp Ruby Deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, azure, azure-web-app-service

After carefully read all Azure tutorials I wasn't able to deploy my application.

I used the follow steps:

1. Create a new Web App from Azure Portal Linux with Ruby 2.3 container
2. Configure local git repository with username and password
3. Fork a hello-workd from Microsoft, from this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-ruby) and from this [repo](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ruby-docs-hello-world)
4. After restart the Web App I got the message:

   ```
   Service Unavailable
   ```

I can't connect using SSH, but, using Kudu, I was able to check the log files. Apparently, the problem is regard with Ruby dependencies, but I have no idea how to solve.

```
2018-02-06 00:54:43.965 INFO  - Logging is not enabled for this container.
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
2018-02-06 00:54:48.292 INFO  - Container logs
2018-02-06T00:54:45.106381390Z Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
2018-02-06T00:54:45.313181989Z Bundle install with no 'without' options
2018-02-06T00:54:45.313337691Z Defaulting gem installation directory to /tmp/bundle
2018-02-06T00:54:45.313459292Z Defaulting site config directory to /home/site/config
2018-02-06T00:54:45.313575793Z Generating a secret key base
2018-02-06T00:54:45.641497487Z RAILS_ENV set to production
2018-02-06T00:54:45.641616888Z Removing any leftover pids if present
2018-02-06T00:54:45.649293251Z Running bundle check
2018-02-06T00:54:45.649606153Z /opt/startup.sh: line 67: [: : integer expression expected
2018-02-06T00:54:46.700604188Z You are replacing the current local value of path, which is currently "/home/site/wwwroot/vendor/bundle"
2018-02-06T00:54:47.793612367Z missing dependencies, try redeploying

2018-02-06 00:54:48.293 ERROR - Container xxx for site xxx has exited, failing site start
```

Anyone did go thru on this?
I suspect maybe is related to some app configurations, but as far I read, it's optional.

Comment: How did you check logs? I also want to check it to see error. I am also getting `Service Unavailable` error.

Comment: The log deployment is under log folder inside site folder. The application log, is inside wwwroot folder. You need to check both in order to assure if the container was properly deployed or if it is a application error, after deployment.

Comment: I can't see any log folder or file inside `wwwroot`. Can you tell me which file I need to check in both `site` and `wwwroot` folder.

Comment: The log of Ruby app is inside wwwroot, the folder is log.

Comment: The access full log of container, you need to activate. These logs are in /site/LogFiles. How to activate https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics.